# Hashtag in Angular Route & Paypal ReturnUrl

Tags: php, angular, paypal

I am working with a project in PHP 5 and Angular 1.5.x, where I am integrating [PayPal's subscription method](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/) through their API. When creating a subscription, a return_url and cancel_url needs to be specified for user approved and cancelled actions respectively. Since I am working with Angular, I have hashtag in the Angular routes, so I need to specify the urls like this:

```
...
'return_url' => 'https://my-url.com/#/cancelUrl',
'cancel_url' => 'https://my-url.com/#/returnUrl',
...
```

In the subscription form, the urls get appended with Paypal subscription parameters such as subscription_id, ba_token and token, so the expected url should be like this:

```
https://my-url.com/#/returnUrl?subscription_id=I-FCUE7BCN9R39&ba_token=BA-8S49206281184340W&token=0KD48595W00078038
```

However, when PayPal puts these links in it's subscription form, they get transformed to something like this:

```
https://my-url.com/?subscription_id=I-L62FUG292EAV&ba_token=BA-6H592267V22776137#/returnUrl&token=1PM62428VT318845Y
```

Hence, the routing gets messed up and does not navigate to the proper route that I have setup for these urls

What I'd like to know is, without going through the trouble of removing hashtag from all Angular route url, is there anything i could do to make the PayPal parameters correctly append into the urls?

Comment: use  PathLocationStrategy then by setting `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false })`

Comment: this will remove  # from the url's in your app

Comment: @JoelJoseph unfortunately that's what I'm trying to avoid. I know the # can easily be removed from the Angular routes, but then I'd also have to remove all the links/variables in various files in the project that already have the # in them. So was thinking whether there was another way

Comment: I have a same problem with angular routing URL as a return URL.. And I can't found any solution. If you have any solution then please help me..
I was integrate paypal in angular before two year ago at that time that  was perfect working, but in last update of my product, when I check my payment flow, at that time I got this issue.